# What kind of Object Notation is this?

Tags: json, object, notation

I was given some files to parse for objects and it looks like JSON but it is not well formatted if so.
The file looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": { 
        "Version": "2.1", 
        "Scanner": "Win32" 
        }
    },
    "Scan": { (...) }, 
    "Scan": { (...) }, 
    "Summary": { (...) } 
}
```

And so Parsin it will only give me the last "Scan" result.
Is it any known Object Notation?

Thanks

Comment: It's valid JSON, but not a valid dictionary since it has repeat keys. You won't be able to parse it normally.

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestion?

Comment: I've come across stuff like this (also with XML), where it looks broadly valid for the expected format but has some kind of glaring error that makes it non valid. Every time I've seen this kind of thing, it turns out to be because someone has rolled their own JSON encoder or XML builder rather than using standard libraries. Why developers persist in doing this is beyond me, but I've come across it often enough to know that there must be a lot of systems out there like this.

Comment: Thanks. it actually looks like "valid" XML, maybe converting it to xml and working this way may actually work.

Comment: @mortain Nope, unfortunately. I've never had to deal with this before. Ask yourself this though: how do you expect it to be parsed. If your going to parse it as an actual Javascript object, it won't be able to have duplicate keys, so what do you want to happen to the duplicated keys?

Comment: @Carcigenicate You're right, but actually I could do it in http://codebeautify.org/jsontoxml, somehow.
[EDITED] Nevermind, it didn't